# Custom Parse Query Paging

Tags: android, performance, parse-platform

I am looking to create an Instagram-esque feed in my app. The problem I am running into is querying the database and populating my listview in an efficient manner. It seems as if the app is populating the ListView all at once, and so I must wait for the entire query to be finished before anything displays.

This query contains a imagefile, which I have been able to reduce down to 50kb and 2 string fields per list item.

I have looked into Paging queries and have tried to construct something similar, all the examples I have been able to find do not have it set up in a ParseQueryAdapter class.

Here is the code I am trying to implement.

```
    public CustomFeedAdapter(Context context) {
    super(context, new ParseQueryAdapter.QueryFactory<PUpload>() {
        public ParseQuery<PUpload> create() {
            ParseQuery<PUpload> query = new ParseQuery<PUpload>(
                    "PUpload");
            query.whereEqualTo("user", ParseUser.getCurrentUser());
            query.orderByDescending("createdAt");
            query.setLimit(25);
            query.setSkip(0);

            return query;
        }
    });
}
```

Comment: If the data is not changing all that often, then you might want to look into Parse Local Datastore. Then once loaded, they will show up instantly in the ListView.

Comment: I am researching that now. The data will be changing very frequently depending on the users usage/friends usage. It is an instagram-like app in regards to the feed aspect.

Comment: Still, despite being pretty much 'live data', I would think that Local Datastore might be the key. Then you can hide the download of new content and update the list only when the data is locally available, instead of waiting for a network request.

Comment: But when you have a long list of even 1000 values, getting from Local Datastore would be painfully slow.